# c# Wpf datagrid databinding to IOC Class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, caliburn.micro

I've made a WPF program with Caliburn Micro, where I used singleton classes for my global variables, which are used in many forms and controls.

Now I understand that static classes are not recommended, so I want to refactor them away using an IoC container.

But I am unsure of how can I bind, for example, a datagrid to a class managed by the IoC container from within my xaml.

Before, I had

```
<Datagid ItemSource = "Source={x:StaticResource statics.class.instance}" ...
```

How can I create a binding that works against the IoC container?

Comment: Do you have instances of those classes? Make them properties and bind to those `ItemsSource="{Binding SomeInstanceProperty.SomePropertyOfInstance}"`.

Comment: Are you really using MVVM?  Becasue you'd have a view model, and it would have properties, and you could fill those properties with values retrieved from your IoC container, and then bind your datagrid's items source to one of those properties.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it:

The view: **MyView.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.MyView">
   <DockPanel>
      <Datagid Name="MyItems"/>
   </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The view model: **MyViewModel.cs**

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
   class MyViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
   {
      public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems { get; }

      public MyViewModel(MyStaticClass myStaticClass)
      {
         MyItems = ConvertMyStaticClassToObservableCollection(myStaticClass);
      }

      ObservableCollection<MyItem> ConvertMyStaticClassToObservabeCollection(MyStaticClass myStaticClass)
      {
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

Finally, you need to make sure to set up your static class as a singleton using your IoC container.  Here's how you'd do it using SimpleInjector, inside **MyBootstrapper.cs**:

```
protected override void Configure()
{
    _container = new Container();

    _container.Register<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
    _container.Register<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();

    _container.RegisterSingleton<MyStaticClass>();

    _container.Verify();
}
```